# Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected

Tags: charging, power-on

Is it possible to automatically power on the device once the charger is connected given that the device is initially turned off?

Answer (score 12):

The battery charging graphic is displayed by `/system/bin/playlpm` file on Samsung devices.

If you are root, you can edit this file to:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

And be sure to add those permissions to the file:

```
chmod 0755 /system/bin/playlpm
chown root.shell /system/bin/playlpm
```

Your device will now boot when plugged

Comment: Hi, I have a Cyanogenmod device , do you know how can I do this on cyanogenmod ? Thanks

Comment: This only works on Samsung devices. [This](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/68291-auto-start-boot-power-on-when-charger-connected/) may be useful for you

Comment: If you're trying to do this, make sure you don't have carriage returns in your playlpm file or it won't work.

Answer (score 12):

`fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0` is the genuine method if your device supports. It's Google's [recommended](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/unlock-trusty#off-mode-charging) method but not all OEMs/vendors implement the command in bootloader. Or on some devices it's reset on next reboot. If `off-mode-charge` is disabled, bootloader won't pass `androidboot.mode=charger` commandline parameter to kernel when charger is inserted, so device boots normally.

Otherwise when `ro.bootmode` property is set to `charger` on boot, `init` doesn't continue the [normal boot process](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/init/init.cpp#738). Instead limited number of services are started and charging animation is displayed. So you can instruct `init` to reboot the device whenever charger mode is detected. Create a new `.rc` file or edit any existing one:

```
# /system/etc/init/off_mode_charge.rc

on charger
    setprop sys.powerctl reboot,leaving-off-mode-charging
```

Or execute `reboot` binary:

```
on charger
    exec - -- /system/bin/reboot leaving-off-mode-charging
```

But if SELinux is enforcing, stock policy may not let `init` execute `/system/bin/reboot`. So use Magisk's context (or whatever rooting solution you use):

```
on charger
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/reboot
```

Don't forget to set permissions on `*.rc` file (`chown 0.0`, `chmod 0644`, `chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0`).

It's also possible to continue boot process instead of restarting the device by replacing `class_start charger` with `trigger late-init` in [`/init.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/rootdir/init.rc#687) file:

```
on charger
    #class_start charger
    trigger late-init
```

Or by setting property [`sys.boot_from_charger_mode`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/rootdir/init.rc#262):

```
on charger
    setprop sys.boot_from_charger_mode 1
```

- This method should work on all devices irrespective of OEM as it doesn't depend on vendor-specific charging binaries like `playlpm`, `battery_charging`, `chargeonlymode`, `zchgd`, `kpoc_charger` and so on.
- Also replacing binaries of important services like `healthd` - which take care of a lot of things related to battery, storage etc. - is not a good idea. In this case if the service runs both in `charger` and `normal` mode, device may get into bootloop.
- On non-System-as-Root devices it's not necessary to modify `/system` partition (e.g. if you don't want to break `dm-verity` for OTA updates to work). Simply unpack `boot.img` and edit `/init.rc` file in `ramdisk`.
- Though unnecessary, it's also possible to execute an `init.d` script from `.rc` file. For reference see [How to run an executable on boot?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526) and [How to power off when charger is removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214074/218526).

---

**RELATED:**

- [Android device load process](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205140/218526)

Comment: @JeffLuyet thanks for the path correction. You can ask a new question if something isn't properly addressed in existing questions/answers. I just saw your proposed edit by-chance. No notification is sent. // I don't know exactly why it didn't work for you. I have been playing with `init`'s `.rc` file at least since Android 7. And it always worked. Usually SELinux is the most problematic part. You should have seen at kernel logs (`dmesg`) right after first failed attempt. `init` logs its events to kernel log. That's how the problem can be identified.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you for your post here. I have the following issue, do I have to be root for this? I get 

`gta3xlwifi:/etc/init $ cat > off-mode-charge.rc
/system/bin/sh: can't create off-mode-charge.rc: Read-only file system`

Comment: @omega1 definitely you need to be root. Or at least need to have custom recovery to modify `boot.img` or `/system` from there. None of the methods to automatically power on when charger is connected can work without root, except `fastboot oem off-mode-charge` (if supported on your device).

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for confirming. It does not support  `fastboot oem off-mode-charge` and I have failed miserably at rooting the device (Samsung SM-T510), I've followed every guide I can find and either get stuck with errors or fail at different parts of the steps (I must be missing something). I managed to load into TWRP, could I modify boot.img from there? I might look that up and see if I can do it that way. Who'd have thought it would be so hard!?

Comment: I am getting the error `FAILED (remote: 'not support on security')`. What gives?

Answer (score 4):

So, there are many ways to do so. The most proper one, as always [supported](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/unlock-trusty#off-mode-charging) by Google (and more and more by others, e.g. [nvidia](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/legacy-products/12/249352/auto-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connecte/) from nougat) is this fastboot command

```
fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0
```

Otherwise, you can either hijack the charging binary (not guaranteed to be possible on all devices, but just requires root) or patch your ramdisk (theoretically universal, but will require an unlocked bootloader).

For the first solution, you'll have to find somewhere in your system partition (usually the *bin* folder) where the program in charge of the battery animation and all resides. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977502/auto-boot-from-offline-charging-when-charged-on-sony-xperia-or-disable-offline-c) [common](https://appdictive.dk/blog/android/how-to/2017/04/20/disabeling_offline_charge_on_android/) [names](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1187631&page=10):

- Motorola: `charge_only_mode`
- Mediatek: `kpoc_charger` or `ipod`
- Htc: `chargemon` or `zchgd`
- Samsung: `playlpm` or `lpm`
- Sony: `chargemon` or `battery_charging`
- Most(?) AOSP-based roms: `healthd`

Once found, you can just replace it with a script such as that above by IET_DEMO.

Touching the kernel is instead something I don't feel like explaining and recommending if you don't know what you are doing.

Just for the records then, I'd just like to underline that offline charging exists because the boot process is fairly energy intensive, and especially on older phones without even fast charging the power draw from the system could be higher than that on the plug.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this working for ZTE Force (Boost Force, Sprint Force, etc).

I used IET_DEMO's answer, but replaced the file located at `/system/bin/battery_charging` with this code:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

Comment: Hi, I have a Cyanogenmod device , do you know how can I do this on cyanogenmod ? Thanks

Comment: You'll need these commands:  `adb shell 'su -c mount -o rw,remount /system'` and `adb shell su -c 'chmod 755 /system/bin/battery_charging'` and `adb shell su -c 'chown root.shell /system/bin/battery_charging'`

Answer (score 2):

For some older Samsung devices, this can be accomplished through [NoMoarPowah!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/themes-apps/app-nomoarpowah-charging-screen-t1167608):

> NoMoarPowah! can automatically reboot into Android when charging is done. Either when fully charged, or when the battery level reaches 15% and Android has enough juice to run.

You need root and you probably don't want to do it unless you really know what you're doing, since I would expect this to modify important system files.

---

It looks like this has been removed from the Play Store, but you can probably find the APK hosted elsewhere.  (I don't have a trusted link offhand.)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel is loaded at a later stage in the [boot-up process](http://elinux.org/Android_Booting), so any modifications to it would not have any effect for when the device is powered off.

This functionality really depends on each device's hardware, most likely in the bootloader (more knowledgeable editors feel free to correct me.)  For example, my Motorola Atrix 4G phone begins booting up when I connect a charger, while my Samsung Galaxy Tab does not - it displays the "Battery Charging" graphic and requires being powered on manually.

Comment: so what brings up the Battery charging graphic on the screen ?!...now the bootloader is called when you hit on the power button manually, but what piece of code displays the battery charging graph on the screen ?!

Comment: In powered off state device's behavior on hardware events like power button and charger obviously depends on lower level code including SoC/PMIC firmware and bootloaders. But I haven't seen an Android device on which bootloader handles charging entirely itself without involving OS (not sure if there were in 2012). Bootloader hands over charge to Android kernel and even `init` is started. The only difference is that `/data` (and possibly other filesystems) are not mounted and a limited set of services is started as compared to normal userspace.