# Automatically power on Nexus 7 when plugged in

Tags: root-access, nexus-7, power-on

Is there any way to power on Nexus 7 2012 automatically when charging started? I want to use Nexus 7 as a car PC, so I need this feature for energy economy.

PS - my Nexus 7 is rooted and uses CM 10.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Comment: This thread covers Samsung only. Is there any option for other devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to be able to:

- Power off tablet when car is off
- Use command

  **`fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0`**

  ---
- To reset to normal, change the **`0`** to **`1`**
- Event for Tasker profile : [Power](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html)

Comment: How exactly did you do that?

Comment: @Tardo What part don't you understand? First, is what you want the tablet to do. Second, is the command used to accomplish that task. Third, is how to change it back for normal operation. You should read the **Tasker** website and the forums related to the app, for in-depth info.

Comment: I've got it. The command is the task, execute a shell command. But what is the event you're setting as a Profile to identify when the charger is connected?

Comment: ***POWER*** [http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/help/sh_index.html)

Comment: `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0` doesn't work on my chinese tablet..

Comment: @Tardo contact the manufacturer, your tablet might not support fastboot.

Comment: My guess is that fastboot is a file inside /system/bin ? Is it right?

Comment: @Tardo No it isn't located in your android device. It would located in your computer, wherever you installed android SDK (<path to SDK>\sdk\platform-tools\fastboot.exe -for windows, Linux would be system/core/fastboot). Fastboot is a tool used to manipulate the flash partitions of an android device. I still recommend contacting your manufacturer and possibly searching out a forum dealing specifically with  your device (same hardware and etc.)