# Auto turn on after power on for an Android-based device

Tags: charging, boot, reboot, power-on

If I'm not mistaken, if an Android-based device is turned off (or powers down due to completely exhausted battery) and then is charged up again, it will automatically boot only to battery charging mode<sup>1</sup>.

Is there anything (configuration switch, external application etc.), that would allow me to introduce such behavior to any other Android-based device? Or is this kind of behavior limited to mods only and I'd have to write my one mod to accomplish this?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The only exception, that I'm aware of, is my old good LG 540 with CyanogenMod 7 on board, which (for the reasons beyond my imagination, since I'm rooting or modding newbie) always powers on to full system, when charged up from off state.</sub>

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "boot to battery charging mode"? Do you mean the battery charging animation?

Comment: Exactly! I plug-in charging cable on completely turned off device, it turns on and a nice battery charging animation appears.

Comment: Related: [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20021/16575)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a kernel (feature known as recovery) and you can't change this, unless you change your kernel with desired option enabled.

Didn't try this out, but [Autosleeper Auto power ON-OFF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.as.powerchecker&hl=en) application seems to do, what you want.

Comment: Autosleeper power ON-OFF looks like it puts your phone to sleep on power failure / turning off the car, then wakes it back up when the power is restored / the car is turned back on. So if the battery was drained completely, I don't see how it would turn the device back on.