# is there a way to reboot device without any keys and usb debugging turned off

Tags: reboot

I had been using my phone for last 1.5 year ( Lava z90). But recently it's power off button and volume buttom are not working and also my usb debugging is turned off.2 days back my phone is switched off and I am not able to swich on it. Is there a way to turn it on?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. consider repairing the power button. you can try to [readback](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220584) something, as most flash tools have auto-reboot functionality. with this trick you should be able to reach [fastboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220089) mode where you can configure charging behavior. if you don't afraid of permanently bricking your device you can also flash modified [para](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221365) partition (experts only)