# Turn phone on with damaged power & volume button?

Tags: samsung, fastboot, power-on

if Power and volume button is busted, is it possible to turn phone on by using adb or fastboot or any other method?

Or may be, How a powered off phone communicate with the power button and other things(i.e charging animation,volume button etc)? perhaps is it possible to tweak this communication to gain access externally?

**Curious, solving this issue by software means, possible?**

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turning on with ADB and SDK tools?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221365/turning-on-with-adb-and-sdk-tools)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks, the link was helpful. however it does not answer my question.

Comment: "depends on how deep you read" True! if im not wrong, first you described- how to root. Then the provided link was about- turn phone on(a switched off one) automatically once connected to a charger. But for these processes i.e flashing magisk_boot.tar & etc  dont i need a turned on phone? the device is samsung. And sorry for late reply

Comment: by externally i mainly meant 3rd partly(application tools).

external access -access a device by a 3rd partly application like adb/fastboot.if possible, on a nonroot device.

software(on device itself/on host via usb?)- on a host . as i cant turn on the device. also to avoid answers/comments suggesting, replace power and volume button.

("turn phone on/external access/communicate with the power button")?- all 3 of them. But mainly+satisfiied "turn phone on". As mentioned **CURIOUS!**. i am curious(thats why the other 2). And lastly  thanks a lot for the replays and your precious time.

Comment: no prob. And Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not mention your phone model, so we can only give broad answer:

On my samsung tablet there is easy way without power button. only press Volume Down + Home Button + connect charger will bring up odin mode splash screen (with additional options). with Volume Down select reboot

---

For more details on how things work please read the linked questions:

> *How a powered off phone communicate with the power button*

[What is the fastest way to shutdown unrooted Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/215736)

> *perhaps it is possible to tweak this communication to gain access externally*

very hard challenge and not possible by software only, this kind of communication is proprietary low level protocol. furthermore that requires physical access to pcb board

> *is it possible to turn phone on by using adb or fastboot*

No. external access via usb by

- `adb` requires running adb daemon on device. that is only the case in recovery or boot mode
- `fastboot` requires device running on fastboot mode, which is generally not supported on samsung devices
- other application on host requires device running in other mode. Such applications are flash tools like Odin/heimdall or EDL programmer tools (qualcomm only)

---

The [auto-reboot after flash trick without power button](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220089) is similar on most flash tools. It works best on Mediatek devices because preloader mode is activated only by plug in usb cable without pressing any button.
Samsung download mode can be achieved with JIG dongle.

Flashing official stock ROM will reboot phone when done with flashing