# Can I send start command to my android phone in linux using serial command

Tags: boot, htc-10

I can't use my phone's start button, it's non-functional and in shutdown state.[similar problem but can't access battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/131248/my-phones-power-button-has-gone-bad-can-i-use-my-computer-to-send-a-usb-comman)
Can I send start command using Linux USB serial communication for this?

If it's probable, which port should I use to send that start command.

Here difference in my port list.

| Connected | No Connection |
| --- | --- |
| bsg | ------------------------ |
| cdrom | ------------------------ |
| sr0 | ------------------------ |

Comment: That is hardware specific. The only devices I know that have an active USB port when device is off are those with a Mediatek CPU/SoC.