# Boot Samsung Galaxy S7 Android when charger is connected

Tags: rooting, root-access, 6.0-marshmallow, charging, reboot

I want to boot up my samsung s7 when charging is end and on connecting charger that it get auto boot.
 I have lpm file in /system/bin directory but replacing the script , it does not work for me.Any help ?

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

Comment: [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app can help. *Trigger:* power connected *Action:*Reboot*

Comment: @beeshyams If I read the question correctly, the device is turned off when connected to the charger. I don't think Macrodroid fires then :)

Comment: @Izzy: possible that your interpretation is correct and so is the obvious conclusion of being unable to awaken the dead :) let's hope OP clarifies

Comment: Yes actually i researched google lot of articles that asked me to root the mobile and find the script that cause charging animation so i found it in samsung s7 with name lpm. i replaced the animation script with reboot script but its not working . may be samsung made it secure or i am mistaking something.
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected

Comment: yes  
"Macrodroid"  is not booting android mobile when mobile is turned off.