# Is it possible to power on Android device with charger?

Tags: charging, boot, power-on

I don't know if it is unusual, but it happened this morning. I have a pretty old Android tablet with a partially working power button. Partially working in the sense, it works sometimes. The tablet is actually not in a good shape. The battery is poor. So I always use it plugged in. The charging port isn't good either. It also works occasionally.

Today morning I was checking if the tablet is still working. I was just plugging the charger in and out, but all of a sudden, it turned on. I tried the same again. But it didn't work.

Is that actually possible??? If so is there any procedure for doing this??

BTW, the tablet is a Micromax tablet running on Android 4.1.2

Comment: Looks like it is possible with [some](https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04139950). Search for user manual of your tablet

Comment: @beeshyams It's a Micromax Funbook P362 tablet

Comment: Sorry but couldn't find any user manual to confirm if that is the expected behaviour or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a device. Some can be powered without a battery at all. One older smartphone I had did that. Yet on my latest phones it's not possible. On one phone if the percentage jumped from 0 to 1%, I could already start using it and the battery would keep charging. But on another phone it needs about 7%, and if I turn it on, I can use it a little bit and it shuts down bringing the battery back to 0%.

One other thing that matters is, not all chargers are the same. Try different ones you have. Some of these "fast charging" ones might work.