# Boot on Charger, power down on charger remove and autostart app

Tags: boot, automation, sony-xperia

I am looking to do the following:

- Auto boot device on charger connection.
- Auto start an app on boot.
- Auto power down on charger disconnection.

It looks like I'll need at least one app to do this, but wondered if there was a single app I can use to achieve what I need (rather than 2 or 3).

I'd rather not root, but would do if I *have* to.

The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab A SM-T510.

Thanks.

**Update :**

I have resolved items 2 and 3 with Tasker, but still stuck with item 1.
I cannot run the fastboot command (so autoboot on charger connect) because Samsung devices do not have fastboot mode. Still looking for a solution to item 1.

Comment: An app is usually not allowed to shut down a device (unless it is a system app from your device manufacturer). For regular apps root permissions are required.

Comment: CLI solutions for 1 and 3 (not possible without root): [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384/218526) , [How to power off when charger is removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214074/218526). Auto starting an app on boot is the app's ability to listen for BOOT_COMOLETED broadcast event and run a service or do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: I have resolved items 2 & 3 but cannot seem to resolve item 1 because Samsung devices do not have a fastboot mode. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @omega1 see my answer to [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)