# Autoboot Samsung Galaxy on Charger connect, but cannot run fastboot command

Tags: samsung, fastboot, samsung-galaxy-tab

I need to autoboot a Samsung Galaxy Tab A (SM-T510) when the charger is connected, I know that to do this, I need to issue the following command to the device `fastboot oem-off-mode charge 0` but as I understand, I Samsung Galaxy's do not have a fastboot mode, so I am stuck now.

I've tried to root the tablet, but failed miserably trying now for last few days getting stuck with one thing or another.

Is there any other way to achieve this (boot device on charger connect)?

I've managed to get int adb shell, but cannot find any relevant files to edit to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer to [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Comment: Your duplicate question: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225675/218526

Comment: @Irfan Latif Thank you, but I have no /system/bin/playlpm or system/bin/lpm files to edit so I cannot follow that guide

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at a different suggested solution, I will try your answer

Comment: @omega1 The only way I could make this to work is by using Samsung KNOX. They have an option that does exactly that.

Comment: @zolakt Thanks for your note, do you have a link or more info on this as I dropped the project but would like to pick it back up again and some time. Thanks.