# Shutdown android device after disconnect charger

Tags: charging, shutdown, development

I need shutdown android system after disconnect charger.

I have android 6.0.1 (rooted), and I'm looking for to power off phone, when it's not charging. I'm looking for programming solution. I have power on phone when I start charging phone. To do it I changed init.rc file. Now I looking for which file I can change, to achive power off phone after disconneted charger.

I have this code in init.rc:

```
on charger
    setprop ro.bootmode "normal"
    setprop sys.powerctl "reboot"
```

To test, I added this to function "on charge"r too:

```
sleep 300
/system/bin/busybox poweroff -f
```

and finally I have:

```
on charger
    setprop ro.bootmode "normal"
    setprop sys.powerctl "reboot"
    sleep 300
    /system/bin/busybox poweroff -f
```

but it didn't work.

I tested:

```
/system/bin/setprop sys.powerctl shutdown
```

```
/system/bin/svc power shutdown
```

```
/system/bin/busybox poweroff -f
```

Phone never shutdown after connect charger (this was only test, I need shutdown after disconnect charger, not after connect, but why this commands didn't work?).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to power off when charger is removed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214074/218526)

Comment: Hej IrfanLatif, yes, I try this script copy-paste to my `init.rc` file, and it didn't work.

Comment: It won't work as it is in `init.rc` file because it's a [`shell` script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script), not an [`init` script](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md).