# fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0 Ressetting back to "1"

Tags: custom-roms, charging, fastboot, redmi

Using "Gzosp-rolex-riva-8.1.0.Stable.1.0-UNOFFICIAL-20180622-1133" on "Redmi 4A"

Upon Using `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0` its working for ONE TIME only,

Once the phone powered on, its getting back to `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 1`

Can Anyone please solve this ??

( OEM Unlocked & Rooted )

Comment: Is there any way to boot android when plugged in with any custom rom or kernal ??

Comment: tried few ,methods on Ground Zero, Havoc and pixel experience on REDMI 4A

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384