# how to turn on phone when power button is broken?

Tags: 7.0-nougat

its a xiomi mi redmi 5a prime.
i can get it to fast boot but since usb debugging is int enabled i cant get it to go to recovery.
mi manager doesn't detect the phone in fast boot as well. Is there any way to fix this apart from taking the phone apart?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20021

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it into fastboot mode, here's how you can bootup your device:

1. Get Google's platform-tools (aka adb), from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools)
2. Boot your phone into fastboot mode
3. Run this command with platform-tools:

```
fastboot reboot
```

Comment: did try that, doesnt work.