# using fastboot to turn on Pocophone F1

Tags: fastboot, bootloader, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

My power button is broken internally, I can't press it to turn on my phone. How should I turn it back on? This is what I do and fail:

Holding volume down and plugging cable I get the fastboot logo, I run Command on SDK.

I enter> fastboot devices (it gives me the device number)

I enter> fastboot reboot OR fastboot boot OR fastboot continue

Everytime I get this error:

**Rebooting                                          FAILED (Write to device failed (Unknown error))
fastboot: error: Command failed**

Using PowerShell on SDK folder or using minimal fastboot I get no error BUT just like before my phone says "press any key to shut down." instead of booting to OS.

What should I do? Thank you (also tell if there's another way to turn it on)

Comment: have you installed adb?

Comment: The Windows command `fastboot` has to be installed. The preferred source is the Android SDK, but there are also minimal installations that contain just `adb` and `fastboot`.

Comment: Robert, I did download fastboot and ran PowerShell by Shift+RightClicking in the downloaded folder. (it has no installation file or copy root)

Comment: why are you using powershell?

Comment: I installed minimal adb and fastboot installer, android SDK  and 15 seconds adb installer. Yet everytime I command reboot my phone says press any key to shut down instead of booting to OS. I use everything cmd, powershell, minimal...

Comment: I edited my situation in the post, please help me fix it.

Comment: use `cmd.exe` and standalone [platform-tools](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384