# Fastboot not working with new Teclast P80H

Tags: fastboot, mediatek

I am developing an in-car product and app.  Previously, I had a Teclast P80H tablet with a micro-USB connector and running Android 7.0.  I was able to enter fastboot mode and from Windows cmd window, issue the Android SDK command "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0".  This successfully reconfigured that older tablet so that, if the tablet was fully shut down and turned off, connecting 5V to the micro-USB jack would cause the tablet to boot up and run.  This was great for my in-car product and app.

Now that old tablet is no longer available, so I'm trying a newer version of the Teclast P80H.  This one has a USB-C connector and runs Android 10.0.  It takes a slightly different method to get into fastboot mode, but I think I've figured it out.  However, when I issue the command "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0" I get a message "FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')".

In order to make sure I really do have the tablet in fastboot mode, I've tried a couple things.  First, issuing "fastboot reboot" does indeed reboot the new tablet like it did with the old tablet.  Even better, the command "fastboot oem get_identifier_token" seems to work, telling me "(bootloader) Identifier token:" and on the next line "(bootloader) ******************".  Well, I've omitted the actual identifier for security purposes, of course, I guess.  But this seems to prove to me that I have the tablet in the right mode to receive the "fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0" command.

But it seems like maybe this version of the tablet's oem commands doesn't include "off-mode-charge".  Perhaps the name or syntax has changed.  But I don't know how to find out.  While "fastboot help" works, it seems that 'fastboot oem help" doesn't.  I don't know how to figure out how to configure this new tablet.

Again, my objective is for the tablet to boot up from full shutdown, whenever 5V is applied through the USB-C connector.  BTW, I'm using the USB-C to USB-A cable that came with the tablet, plugging the USB-A end into my Windows 10 computer.

I did re-install the latest Android Studio.  I also updated the SDK to Android 10.  (It was Android 9.)  However, the fastboot.exe program remains with an 11/14/2019 file date, perhaps the original date I installed it.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for trying, Robert.  But as I said, I've been using fastboot successfully already on the prior model of Teclast P80H (with micro-usb connector, Android 7.0).  So, as politely expressed as I'm able, your comment is both incorrect and unhelpful.  Any ideas instead on how to move forward?  (Actually, I may try researching MediaTek...  Thanks for that.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Comment: *sed -i '0,/off-mode-charge=1/s/off-mode-charge=1/off-mode-charge=0/' $(find /dev/block -name by-name)/para* from TWRP recovery will change the value located in para partition (mediatek devices)

Comment: @alecxs your link and 'sed' command look promising.  However, they are beyond my experience/ability at this time.  This is for a new small business product.  I'd like to private message you about direct help, and I've seen your profile, but I don't see how to send a private message...