# Is there any options to Boot Android device on connecting to power supply without root?

Tags: power-on, auto-start

I wish to know if there is any options to boot android device automatically on connecting to power supply. i am not considering **rooting options** as i was planning for production application.

I have tried to enter into fastbood mode without much success .. trying on samsung galaxy tab A.   [image]

Comment: Boot from powered off state? Not possible without root. Except if hardware/ROM/bootloader already support the feature. My answer explains what's the minimum requirement to achieve this: [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384/218526)

Comment: @IrfanLatif  I have tried to enter fastboot mode without success .. updated image from my tablet as well .. any help would be highly appreciated ..  its not detecting in fastboot mode

Comment: Samsung devices have odin mode, not fastboot. You can search about it. I don't have any personal experience with Samsung devices.