# Phone won't stay off when charging Motorola Edge Plus on Android 10 and above

Tags: charging, motorola, power-on

After getting a replacement phone from Verizon, the new Motorola Edge Plus will not stay powered off while charging, as the last one did.

After looking on the forums, I enabled developer options, but "stay awake" was not enabled.

The problem persists with 5 and 15W chargers, as well as Qi charging.

It turns on when plugged in if it was previously off, and restarts automatically if I turn it off while it is already plugged in.

To be clear, all I want to do is be able to turn the phone off and see its charging progress without turning the whole phone on.

Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/20021

Answer (score 1):

I WAS WRONG!

I NEVER would have thought this was the cause, but I was wrong and I thought you deserved an update. I cannot explain why so many people were confirming that their phones would refuse to stay off... but I guess that was all just one giant red herring.

I was having trouble getting my USB-C cable to charge my phone, I would have to keep it at an odd angle in order for it to charge. I got tired of this, so I decided to clean out the USB port. I shut off my phone, grabbed a sewing needle, and then removed all the pocket lint that had collected in the USB-C port on my phone. After that, I plugged it in to charge and... it didn't turn on. Before today, it would power on the instant I plugged it in. Now, it stays off! I cannot tell you how much I HATE being wrong, but I also didn't want to leave you with an incorrect answer.

In fact... now that I think of it, all of the Android phones that people are "confirming" will automatically turn back on, they all have USB-C. At the risk of being wrong again, I wonder if it's a combination of some people just having dirty USB ports and some phones genuinely having that feature.

I apologize for misleading you. All of the data I painstakingly collected is now suspect. I am 100% certain that at least some modern phones have this "feature" but it is clear to me that I was completely wrong in my assertion that this was a new feature being pushed by Google... IT seemed obvious based on everything I was reading...

At least this explains why I couldn't find any official documentation on it...

PS:

I doubt your charging port is dirty since it is a new phone, but it is worth trying a different cable, a different charger, and if all else fails, cleaning the port anyway. Please downvote my previous answer so I do not accidentally mislead anyone. I will post a comment under that answer saying I was wrong, that way I don't confuse future readers

Comment: LOL.  Thank you very much for the update.  This is extra funny because the first computer bugs were literally bugs (usually moths) that were attracted to the light and heat of the tubes.  Here we are, many decades later, and now it's pocket lint!  What's next, belly button lint? :)

Answer (score 1):

I thought I was going crazy. I shut my phone off while the charger is plugged in. And an hour later the phone turns on automatically! Waking me up out of a dead sleep because I'm hearing "Hello Moto!" I was able to charge my phone overnight without it having to be turned on before. I don't like this feature. If I understand this correctly, I need to shut the phone off completely and then I can plug in my charger. To allow the phone to stay off while charging.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this any more. All modern phones running the latest version of Android will automatically turn on if they detect power input, this is a safety feature that (as far as I am aware) you can not disable. If you would like to have your phone stay powered off while charging, you must downgrade to an earlier version of Android.

I wasn't happy when I discovered it as well, and I searched for days to find a straight answer, which is surprisingly difficult to find. This answer is based on dozens of posts on multiple sites and hours of scrolling through community responses to similar questions. My phone is a Pixel 3 XL, but it doesn't seem to matter what model, it seems to be the same across all of the latest makes and models of phones that run the latest Android. This "feature" seems to have been implemented in 2018 for Nexus and Pixel phones, although it is difficult to pinpoint when exactly. From then on, it began to pop up in other manufacturer's devices as well, so I'm guessing this is an industry standard now. I also found that most Apple devices do this as well, from seemingly the iPhone 5 onward, though I'm not as sure about that since I wasn't specifically looking up Apple phones.

I hope this helps, and secretly I hope I'm wrong and there is some secret hidden menu somewhere that will disable this function.

Cheers.

****EDIT****

New undisputable evidence has proven me 100% wrong. 3 days of research only to come to the wrong conclusion. Any future readers, please disregard this answer, as it is wrong. Some of the things I said are still probably true, some phones definitely have this "feature" if you can call it that, but it is NOT a new industry standard being pushed by Google. In my case, it ended up being a dirty charging port.

Comment: That's kind of you to provide our community with the results of your research.  Thanks!  Upvoted.  Why is this considered a "safety feature"?

Comment: I **THINK** it has something to do with being on so you can dial 911 at a moment's notice if you have to, instead of waiting for your phone to boot. Charging your phone while it is powered on is only slightly slower than with it off so I guess they consider it a fair trade off? It's extremely difficult to get a straight answer... When I was looking, almost all of the stuff I could find was more "extrapolated from" rather than "directly stated" so please take my answer with a big grain of salt. always staying on for easy access to emergency services -seems- to be the most common excuse

Comment: Thanks so much for the update. That's a stupid reason, so it's probably correct. ;)  Personally, I think it should be up to the user to decide which is more important: access to emergency services now, or later.  I once took a phone on an expedition, and needed to charge it at a brief stopover.  It turned on when I tried to charge it, which caused all sorts of issues, and also resulted in less battery power when I really needed it.  But I'm sure I'm "preaching to the choir" here... :)

Comment: New undisputable evidence has proven me 100% wrong.

Comment: LOL.  No problem.  And no roasting. ;)  Thank you so much for the update!