# Start button broke, USB debugging NOT enabled, need to start phone!

Tags: adb, fastboot

Basically I have a Moto X4 without USB debugging enabled and the start button doesn't work.  I can boot up to AP Fastboot (the screen with the little droid in the background), but I don't have USB enabled, so when I connect the phone via USB cord to my laptop, ADB won't recognize it (so I can't reboot using ADB).

Is there anything I can do!?  I don't want to do anything "security sketchy" here: just start it up to get to the point where I can enter my password/use fingerprint ID.

Would an OTG adaptor work!?

Comment: How do you manage to make the device boot without a working power button?

Comment: I input the charging cord and simultaneously hit the volume button.  Both volume buttons work.

Comment: you don't need usb-debugging for fastboot commands. install bootloader interface drivers and `fastboot reboot`

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to follow https://www.droidwin.com/install-google-android-bootloader-interface-drivers/ to do that. But, I run into two problems

1) All I see in Device Manager is Motorola ADB Interface, and I get an error when I try to update using the Android USB Driver.

2) When I go to a command prompt in the Platform-Tools folder, I get "List of Devices Attached" and nothing is listed.  Also when I enter ADB reboot bootloader, I get "no devices/emulators found."

Comment: Nevermind it worked!

Comment: maybe interesting for you https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Comment: I basically did what Alecxs suggested, so I don't think I answered it myself.   It didn't seem to work prior though, as my phone wasn't being recognized by ADB.  I guess maybe it was the wrong cord?  I don't know. Because of this I was thinking I needed usb debugging to get my phone recognized

Comment: you are mixing up adb with fastboot. adb is a different mode with different drivers and different program/protocol language. fastboot does not require usb-debugging at all. furthermore you can't start device from adb because adb only works on already running android (with enabled authorized usb-debugging). so the trick to power up was simultaneously input cable + volume down button (fastboot mode)