# How to make Pixel 4 XL automatically turn on once power is connected?

Tags: charging, bootloader, google-pixel

I am trying to recycle my old Pixel 4xl into a screen for my 3D printer. Since it does not hold a charge anymore, I need it to be able to power on when it gets power from the printer. I tried following the instructions from [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected), but none of the files listed in any of the answers exist on my device. I also tried running the command: `fastboot oem off-mode-charge 0`, but it is giving me an unknown OEM command error. I am using LineageOS 19 on the device.

Comment: I must've missed it when I first read the post, but the magisk solution worked!