# How to make autostart Xiaomi Mi 11 lite 5g

Tags: xiaomi, auto-start

how can I make my Xiaomi mi 11 lite to auto-start when I plug the usb cable. Fastboot OEM-mode-charge 0 doesn't work.

Comment: [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221384/218526).